# Wordpress - How to send an email notification when page is loaded?

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am currently looking for a way to send an email notification with WordPress website. So for example, when user visits page A, there'll be an email notification sent in the background.

I haven't got much experience with web development in WordPress environment, so can anyone give me a pointer here? Where should I start?

Thanks.

Edit:

I have tried both mail() & wp_mail() functions but none of them seemed to work for me. When I visited that page, no email got sent out. I've also checked the template for that page, which is just default template. Perhaps I was editing the wrong file??

Edit2:

I guess mail function probably hasn't yet been enabled by the hosting provider.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much, just with some texts and images.

Comment: You need user's email address for that.

Comment: Yeah for that part, I will get user's email address from cookie or session variable. All the user info actually comes from ContactForm7 plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a very basic piece of php code that sends an html email.

```
<?php
if(is_page(123))
{

$fromName = 'Auto email notification system';

$subject = 'Confirmed';

/* Mail Address */
$toAddr = 'me@domain.com'; 
$bccAddr = 'bccperson@domain.com'; 
$fromAddr = 'no-reply@domain.com';
/* End Mail Address */


/* Mail Body */
$msg = '
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
my messages about confirmation...
</body>
</html>
';

$msg = wordwrap($msg, 70);
/* End Mail Body */


/* Mail Headers Setup */
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
$headers[] = "From: ".$fromName." <".$fromAddr.">";
$headers[] = "Bcc: <".$bccAddr.">";
/* End Mail Headers Setup */


mail($toAddr, $subject, $msg, implode("\r\n", $headers));

}
?>
```

And I placed above code in header.php file, towards the bottom and it worked for me.

Thank you guys for all the suggestions and help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want PHP's [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function to send the email and something like WordPress [is_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) to identify the pages when you want to send email, so

```
<?php 
if(is_page()) :
  mail('email@address.com','My Subject','My Message');
endif;
?>
```

Also, have a look at the 'Related' section of is_page at the bottom - it may be that you want to use some other determination of which page(s) you want to send the email.

Comment: Do I need to use WP template for the above code? Where should I add it to?

Comment: It depends on what you're doing. Are you creating a custom theme, or using something else? - If it's a custom theme, put it in the theme's functions.php, otherwise a plugin is likely the best route and it should go in your main plugin file. Google WordPress plugins for details on how to create one.

If these don't apply then I need more information on exactly what you have so that I can advise further.

Comment: It's not going to be a custom theme. I just need to add a "send email" type of new function to a original page. The page was already created with some texts and images. I know the pageID from permalink, but I don't know where I can get to its "code-behind" (sorry about the .net term) where I can do server side scripting

Comment: The easiest way is to create a simple plugin - see http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin. It's sounds harder than it is, you just need to create a folder in the plugins directory with a php file containing the code and header information (examples on the link).

Comment: mail function didn't work either. nothing happens when page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Hey @woodykiddy Create a template for the page and put this code in the page.
This condition returns true every time page is loaded.

```
// Example using the array form of $headers
// assumes $to, $subject, $message have already been defined earlier...

$headers[] = 'From: Me Myself <me@example.net>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: Aravind B Codex <abc@wordpress.org>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: iluvwp@wordpress.org'; // note you can just use a simple email address

<?php 
if(is_page()) :
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
endif;
?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thx for the link, I'll take a look at it as well. Just a quick question since you mentioned using a template. How can I have an existing page reference a new template?

Comment: I have updated my question. wp_mail didn't work for some reason.

Comment: Hey woodykiddy
I have tried and it worked. May be you are missing something.

Comment: It is working for me now. But I have got other problems. Are you familiar with Contact Form 7 plugin?

Comment: So post you solution here.
It May be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to create a template. Create a new page my-template.php put this code at the top.

```
<?php
    /*
    Template Name: My New Template
    */
    ?>
```

But it depends on your theme. I have edited twentyten for you. It will give you an idea to create a  template.

```
<?php
    /*
    Template Name: My New Template
    */

    get_header();

    $headers[] = 'From: Me Myself <me@example.net>';
    $headers[] = 'Cc: Aravind B Codex <abc@wordpress.org>';
    $headers[] = 'Cc: iluvwp@wordpress.org'; // note you can just use a simple email address
?>

<?php 
if(is_page()) :
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
endif;
?>


<div id="container">
    <div id="content" role="main">

    <?php
    /* Run the loop to output the page.
     * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
     * called loop-page.php and that will be used instead.
     */
    get_template_part( 'loop', 'page' );
    ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->

</div><!-- #container -->
```

Put email code in it. save it in the template directory.

Go to admin panel and add/edit a page. At the right side of the page there is an option (Template).
Your template will be visible in the drop down there.
Select the template and save the page That's it.

Comment: The problem with this sort of approach is that as soon as the theme is updated, you will have to recreate the template.